# Set value in Textbox after text change

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, textbox, html-editor

I have textbox. On hover i can edit textbox content. After Edit i can save changes, but value of textbox doesn't change in this time, only after refresh.
How change value of textBox?

sample:

```
<input type="radio" name="SelectedSavedSearches" id="Saved_search_<%:s.Value %>" value="<%:s.Value %>" />
                                <label for="Saved_search_<%:s.Value %>">&nbsp;</label>
                                <input type="text" class="saved-search-name def-text-input" value="<%: s.Text %>"/>
                                <button class="saved-search-rename"><strong>Save</strong></button>
```

js:

```
$('.saved-search-rename', container).unbind('click').click(function () {
        var context = $(this);
        var name = context.closest('p').find('.saved-search-name').val();
        if (name != undefined && name.trim() != '') {
            var id = context.closest('p').find('input[name="SelectedSavedSearches"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Account/RenameSavedSearch',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: { ssId: id, newName: name },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (!response.result) {
                        btDialogs.Error(response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            btDialogs.Error('New Name can\'t be empty');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ProfileVerification]
    public JsonResult RenameSavedSearch(int ssId, string newName)
    {
        if (LoggedUser == null)
            return Json(new {result = false, message = "Not Authenficated"});

        var search = _listingManagementService.GetSavedSearch(ssId);
        search.Name = newName;
        var confirmation = _listingManagementService.SaveSearch(search);

        return
            Json(
                new
                    {
                        result = confirmation.WasSuccessful,
                        message = confirmation.WasSuccessful ? "Success" : confirmation.Message
                    });
    }
```

Comment: You want to change the value of the textbox on hover?

Comment: @James i want to change textbox value after click on button save

Comment: What sort of Textbox are you using? Is it and asp:textbox or a standard html textbox? Are you causing a postback on the button click?  Check out the TextBox.OnTextChanged Method that may be what you are after.

Comment: @ChrisBertrand i use standart html-input editor, on button click - yes, it is post

Answer (score 0):

Jquery/Javascript is the solution

```
  UPDATE:
```

I have updated your action in order to return the validated newName

```
[HttpPost]
[ProfileVerification]
public JsonResult RenameSavedSearch(int ssId, string newName)
{
    if (LoggedUser == null)
        return Json(new {result = false, message = "Not Authenficated"});

    var search = _listingManagementService.GetSavedSearch(ssId);
    search.Name = newName;
    var confirmation = _listingManagementService.SaveSearch(search);

    return
        Json(
            new
                {
                    result = confirmation.WasSuccessful,
                    message = confirmation.WasSuccessful ? "Success" : confirmation.Message,
                    validatedNewName=confirmation.WasSuccessful ?search.Name:""
                });
}
```

JS:

```
 $('.saved-search-rename', container).unbind('click').click(function () {
    var context = $(this);
    var nameInput=context.closest('p').find('.saved-search-name');
    var name = nameInput.val();
    if (name != undefined && name.trim() != '') {
        var id = context.closest('p').find('input[name="SelectedSavedSearches"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/RenameSavedSearch',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { ssId: id, newName: name },
            success: function (response) {
                if (!response.result) {
                    btDialogs.Error(response.message);
                }
                nameInput.val(!response.validatedNewName);
            }
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        btDialogs.Error('New Name can\'t be empty');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Sharp ?

Comment: thanks for reply) but when i get only one input - how can i do it? i just can't understand where is new text in textbox...(in html layer)

Comment: So, how do you edit that text? Can you paste append your code to your question?

Comment: add code. i change text in texbox - click on save button - it's post well, but don't change textbox value at this time. To change value i need to refresh page

Comment: I see your code but it seems like you have not provided your Action code: /Account/RenameSavedSearch.

I'm asking this to understand what you really want to do! Please edit again and update it with the code in that action. #Waiting

Comment: Test my update It will work... Humm Don't forget to up-vote ^_^